# My ui-router links are not working, angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Heres My code for my index page, I added ui-view and my app file is called "route-app.js" and have used bower angular ui-router.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="router">
  <head>
      <!-- JS dependencies -->
<!-- AngularJS library -->
          <script src="route-app.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS UI-Router -->
<!-- Our application -->

      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1></h1>
      <a href="#/"></a>

<div ui-view></div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

UI router Js file

```
angular.module('router', ['ui.router'])
.config([function($urlRouterProvider, $StateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $StateProvider

        .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })

}]);
```

Every time I click on the links not pops up. What have I done wrong here.

Comment: what link did you click?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant my href links don't work when using ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

`$StateProvider` should be `$stateProvider` (the first letter is lowercase)

Refer to the documentation here for reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

Also open up your development console, there may be some console errors that might assist you in figuring out what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('router', ['ui.router'])
.config(['urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $StateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $StateProvider

        .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });

}]);
```

The thing is that, you have used array notation for dependency injection but you actually did not inject anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have a couple errors.

The first, and the most important, is that you define your custom scripts prior to including angular itself. So if you look at the console you will see a 'Reference Error: angular is not defined' error.

Second and third, as Alex and Vishal noted, the injection is wrong.
Here are the updated HTML (I removed all the unecessary comments from your code to make it clear where I changed anything. You can of course keep them in your page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="router">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JS dependencies: MUST COME AFTER THE ANGULAR DEPENDENCIES -->
    <script src="route-app.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1></h1>
   <a href="#/"></a>

   <div ui-view></div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the script:

```
angular.module('router', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });

  }]);
```

As an advice, make use of the browser console (by pressing F12). It will give you the errors occuring in your scripts.

**Note**: It is possible to include the custom scripts prior to the angular library, but it's pointless and needs extra code to make it work, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the script file , change the value oftemplateUrl attribute from **'home.html'  to './home.html'**. You have to give root directory.Just giving the file name will not work.

```
angular.module('router', ['ui.router'])
.config([function($urlRouterProvider, $StateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $StateProvider

        .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: './home.html'
    })

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the `ui-sref` attribute and not a plain `href` attribute to make ui-router work properly. Second, your link should not contain a hashtag. In this case, it has to be "/", not "#/".